# How to adjust the cluster size (column) in DoHeatmap plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I want to have a heatmap plot from a Seurat object [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TkEq-xSR7GYe3ZAqkjcTIEpUp-OB8rCf/view?usp=share_link). To read the data, I have tried this code

```
visium_x22117 = Load10X_Spatial(data.dir = "~/PhD_Project_Moh_Huda/Dataset_files/X22117_Visium_scRNA/", filename = "X22117_filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5")
suppressWarnings({visium_x22117 = SCTransform(visium_x22117, assay = "Spatial", verbose = FALSE)
```

visium_x22117})

and to get the plot below I have tried

```
visium_x22117.markers %>%
group_by(cluster) %>%
top_n(n = 10, wt = avg_log2FC) -> top10
heatmap = DoHeatmap(visium_x22117, features = top10$gene)
heatmap
```

[image: heatmap]

However, the plot looks so packed and the column size of cluster 0 is fairly much bigger than the others. I have checked the documentation of the DoHeatmap by using ?DoHeatmap but could not find a way to adjust the size to make the plot looks nicer. How can I make it nicer?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/1984

Answer (score 1):

You could use `theme` with `axis.text` from `ggplot2` because `DoHeatmap` returns a ggplot object. Here is a reproducible example to change the size of the axis labels (You could adjust the size):

```r
library(Seurat)
#> Attaching SeuratObject
library(ggplot2)
data("pbmc_small")
p <- DoHeatmap(object = pbmc_small)
p
```

[image]

```r
p + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yes it works, but the main issue is to adjust the column size so that each column has the same size (column label 0, 1, ..., and 9 from left to right is getting smaller) and is not readable. Is there a way to adjust?

Answer (score 0):

Each cluster is composed of tiny columns that refer to individual cells and since there are different amount of cells within each cluster you can't change it within Seurat. But you can modify it since the heatmap is a ggplot object.

To build on @Quinten's answer, try,

```
p + theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0.5, "cm"))
```

or whatever spacing you want